# Make HTML button appear pressed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simulate

How can I make an HTML button looks like pressed via JavaScript?

I have a button that is sending a network message while pressed and sending another network message when released.

This specific named button may be displayed on more than once in a page or more than one device. So, if any of the identical purpose buttons pressed, I need to make the rest of the copies look like pressed.

How can I achieve that behaviour?

Comment: As in the `:active` state? Either use the CSS active state or add and remove a class on mouse down/up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think it would be an overkill to use JavaScript for this, this done using CSS. Your code would go between the `{ }`.

```
button:active {
    color: red;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

**Warning!**

This will style all the `button` elements, not just one. If you'd like one only then use an ID, if more than one use class.

http://jsfiddle.net/cp4bob0z/

**Edit 1**

**JS Only**

```
<button id="test" onclick="styleButton(this);">Hello!</button>

function styleButton(element) {
     document.getElementById(element.id).className = "yourClassName";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.  He is asking how to make a button change to the `active` state via JavaScript. I don't believe this can be accomplished with just CSS (unless you mirror custom styles from `button:active`, but then it's still not truely in the active state).

Comment: @Jamen I answered the question to my best ability. If the OP decides to make his question clearer, I'll gladly update my post.

Comment: @ceremcem added JS only solution.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose there is no way to make it look like the original pressed style (except for making a fine tune with CSS).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add class to the button in your function.

`$('button').addClass('someclass')`

then just define your class using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, style the active button like so:

```css
button:ative, .active-class {

}
```

That way a clicked button will look the same as if it had the class `active-class`.

From here, you can apply / remove the class in any way you'd please...

```
$(".my-button").on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active-class");
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhdafq73/)

Answer (score 0):

The **`borderStyle`** style property can be set to do this. To show the button depressed, use

```
document.getElementById("myButton").style.borderStyle = "inset";
```

Once completed, use

```
document.getElementById("myButton").style.borderStyle = "outset";
```

to set the button back to normal.